# What is the difference between the new operator and Class.newInstance()?

Tags: java, reflection, new-operator

What is the difference between `new` operator and `Class.forName(...).newInstance()`? Both of them create instances of a class, and I'm not sure what the difference is between them.

Comment: or Class.forName(...).getConstructor(...).newInstance(...)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `new` operator creates a new object of a type that's known statically (at compile-time) and can call any constructor on the object you're trying to create.  It's the preferred way of creating an object - it's fast and the JVM does lots of aggressive optimizations on it.

`Class.forName().newInstance()` is a dynamic construct that looks up a class with a specific name.  It's slower than using `new` because the type of object can't be hardcoded into the bytecode, and because the JVM might have to do permissions checking to ensure that you have the authority to create an object.  It's also partially unsafe because it always uses a zero-argument constructor, and if the object you're trying to create doesn't have a nullary constructor it throws an exception.

In short, use `new` if you know at compile-time what the type of the object is that you want to create.  Use `Class.forName().newInstance()` if you don't know what type of object you'll be making.

Comment: Its a popular Interview question, & this is a great answer... thanks

Comment: you can get constructors that require arguments and use them to instantiate an object through the reflection api.

Comment: Just a note, `ClassNotFoundException` is checked, so you can't compile this: `try { optlib.SomeClass obj = new optlib.SomeClass(); } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}`. In this case, you must use `Class.forName().newInstance()`.

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 16):

`Class.forName("your class name").newInstance()` is useful if you need to instantiate classes dynamically, because you don't have to hard code the class name to create an object.

Imagine a scenario where you load classes dynamically from a remote source. You will know their names but can't import them at compile time. In this case you can't use `new` to create new instances. That's (one reason) why Java offers the `newInstance()` method.

Comment: Great!! It is  useful response!!

Answer (score 5):

Class.forName can only call the default constructor (with no parameters) and
class name can be provided during runtime e.g. the db-driver name read from a configuration file.

Comment: This is not true you can get constructors that require arguments and use them to instantiate an object through the reflection api. However the newInstance method specifically calls the no-arg constructor and requires that it be visible and accessable. templatetypedef's answer is the most complete/correct and informative.

Answer (score 4):

The major difference is `Class.forName('your class name').newInstance()` is dynamic as type need not be hard coded into the code.

Answer (score 3):

`Class.forName("your class name").newInstance()` is used when you want to get an instance form a class work similar to `new`, but it is useful when you want to get instance from a class in a jar file or remote server and you **can not** import it in compile time.

ex: `Class.forName("YOUR JDBC DRIVER").newInstance()`, you can not import the JDBC class at compile time.

Comment: The JDBC example is actually not very good, the necessity to call `newInstance()` only existed for some early versions of the MySQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

`Class.forName('myClass').newInstance()` loads the class if not already loaded. Here it calls the initial constructor and only executes the static part of the constructor.

The `new` operator is used to initialize new objects.

You can create many instances from both the `new` operator and `Class.forName()` difference is the 2nd time you create a `newInstance()` static blocks will not get initialized.

A good example of `Class.forName('myClass).newInstance()` is the JDBC driver

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.JDBC.Driver").newInstance()
```

Comment: What if I use Class<myClass> inst1 = (Class<myClass>)Class.forName('myClass).getInstance()...... Class<myClass> inst2 = (Class<myClass>)Class.forName('myClass).getInstance().............. This will make multiple instances right.

Comment: Well I don't find a method getInstance(). Do You?

Comment: The JDBC example is actually not very good, the necessity to call `newInstance()` only existed for some early versions of the MySQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName` will do a lookup to find the `Class` object for `YourClass`.

Using the new operator should be the same as `YourClass.class.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

While both effectively do the same thing, you should use the new operator instead of doing Class.forName('class').getInstance().  The latter uses the reflection API to lookup the class at runtime.  By using the new operator, the VM will know beforehand that you want to use that class and thus be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `com.statckoverflow.Test`

`Class.forName` - It will load the Test class and return the `Class` class object which contains the metadata of Test class Like name, package, constructor, annotations, methods, fields.

`newInstance()` - Used to instantiate new objects using Java Reflection. Internally zero parameter constructor will be called on the `Test` class. This means `Class` class object will create the `Test` class object by calling the zero parameter constructor, We can use the reflection for details of `Test` class. Like Constructors, methods etc.

`new` operator - Creates the New Object for the class instantiate the `Class` and can call their constructors.

Answer (score -1):

If no zero argument constructor of an object  it will also create an object and it will not throw any exception, please find the below code snippets.

```
try {
    Class o = Class.forName("com.myCompany.MyClass");

    Constructor m = o.getConstructor(Integer.class,String.class);
    m.newInstance(new Integer(0),new String(""));

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```