# What is the difference between a new and an instance keyword?

Tags: java, object, instance, keyword

What is the difference between a new and an instance keyword in java

**Student Class**

```
class student { }
```

**Teacher Class**

```
class Teacher  { }
```

**Test Class**

```
class Test{
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
    
        Object o = Class.forName(args[0]).newInstance();
    
        System.out.println("class creating for " + o.getclass().getName());
    
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612386/what-is-the-difference-between-the-new-operator-and-class-newinstance#:~:text=forName().,authority%20to%20create%20an%20object.

Comment: Did you even try to search for this before posting a question?

Comment: There is no 'new instance' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `new` is used to create an object of those classes which you know them in advance i.e. at compile time but when you don't know the name of class i.e. at runtime you use a `new instance` of creating an object.